# Как обойти графический интерфейс через Bash-скрипт в Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, sh

Доброе время суток! Как управлять процессом только через текстовый режим?

К примеру: `sudo apt-get install mysql-server -y` при установке выводит графический интерфейс с дальнейшим выбором действий.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
*Пример графического интерфейса после команды sudo apt-get install mysql-server -y*

Как избежать графического интерфейса? Нужно для создания полностью автоматизированного bash скрипта (.sh), который просто выполнит те-же команды (нажатие на кнопки), которые мы выполняли бы через графический интерфейс. Заранее всем спасибо!

Comment: DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive (если вас устроит ничего не вводить)

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо большое - будем пробовать!

Comment: Тебе нужен пакет `debconf-utils` и комманды `debconf-get-selections`, `debconf-set-selections`.

Comment: @don Rumata - спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так

```
echo "mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/root-pass password $mysqlpasswd" | sudo debconf-set-selections
echo "mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/re-root-pass password $mysqlpasswd" | sudo debconf-set-selections
echo "mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/remove-data-dir boolean $mysqlpasswd" | sudo debconf-set-selections
echo "mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/data-dir note" | sudo debconf-set-selections
echo "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password $mysqlpasswd" | sudo debconf-set-selections
echo "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password $mysqlpasswd" | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install mysql-server
```

С помощью `echo` и `debconf-set-selections` сначала устанавливается параметры, затем уже ставится mysql-server

Comment: Спасибо большое =)